# tf-serving abnormal exit without error message

Tags: tensorflow-serving

tf-serving abnormal exit without error message

#### System information

OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): ReaHat EL6

TensorFlow Serving installed from (source or binary): source using bazel 0.18.0

TensorFlow Serving version: 1.12.0

#### Describe the problem

i compile the tf-serving using bazel in RHEL 6.9, and start it using:

./model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --model_config_file=./data/models.conf --rest_api_port=8502

models.conf:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: "model_1",
base_path:"/search/work/tf_serving_bin/tensorflow_serving/data/model_data/model_1",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
      latest: {
        num_versions: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Client using C++, and use libCurl to request tf-serving REST api, but, tf-serving often abnormal exits without error message in some minutes.**

**When my client service requests localhost tf-serving, the question occur frequently. But, client service requests tf-serving at other machines, the question do not occur, qps < 100.**

I check memory, cpu idle, etc... no problems is found. so, it is very strange.

export export TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL=1, no error/critical message too.

#### Source code / logs

```
2019-01-09 09:28:35.118183: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:461] Adding/updating models.
2019-01-09 09:28:35.118259: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:558] (Re-)adding model: app_ks_nfm_1
2019-01-09 09:28:35.227383: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:739] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: app_ks_nfm_1 version: 201901072359}
2019-01-09 09:28:35.227424: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: app_ks_nfm_1 version: 201901072359}
2019-01-09 09:28:35.227443: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: app_ks_nfm_1 version: 201901072359}
2019-01-09 09:28:35.227492: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/bundle_shim.cc:363] Attempting to load native SavedModelBundle in bundle-shim from: /search/work/bazel-bin-serving/tensorflow_serving/data/model_data/app_ks_nfm_1/201901072359
2019-01-09 09:28:35.227530: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:31] Reading SavedModel from: /search/work/bazel-bin-serving/tensorflow_serving/data/model_data/app_ks_nfm_1/201901072359
2019-01-09 09:28:35.256712: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:54] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2019-01-09 09:28:35.267728: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-01-09 09:28:35.313087: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:162] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2019-01-09 09:28:38.797633: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:138] Running MainOp with key legacy_init_op on SavedModel bundle.
2019-01-09 09:28:38.803984: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:259] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success. Took 3570131 microseconds.
2019-01-09 09:28:38.804027: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup.cc:83] No warmup data file found at /search/work/bazel-bin-serving/tensorflow_serving/data/model_data/app_ks_nfm_1/201901072359/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
2019-01-09 09:28:38.804148: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:86] Successfully loaded servable version {name: app_ks_nfm_1 version: 201901072359}
2019-01-09 09:28:38.831860: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:286] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
2019-01-09 09:28:38.865243: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:302] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8502 ...
[evhttp_server.cc : 237] RAW: Entering the event loop ...
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. Have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason：the short connection product a large amount of TCP Status 'TIME_WAIT', the available linux system file handle is occupied.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an abnormal exit. It is an indication that the **Server is ready to receive the Inference Requests.**

For clarification, please find the below explanation:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -p 8501:8501 \
  --mount type=bind,\ source=/tmp/tfserving/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_gpu,\
  target=/models/half_plus_two \
  -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two -t tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu &
```

This will run the docker container with the nvidia-docker runtime, launch the TensorFlow Serving Model Server, bind the REST API port 8501, and map our desired model from our host to where models are expected in the container. We also pass the name of the model as an environment variable, which will be important when we query the model.

**TIP: Before querying the model, be sure to wait till you see a message like the following, indicating that the server is ready to receive requests:**

```
2018-07-27 00:07:20.773693: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc:333]
Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
```

**After that Message, just press Enter and you can query the model using the below command**

```
curl -d '{"instances": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}' \
  -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/half_plus_two:predict
```

For more information, refer the below link:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker#gpu_serving_example